Confuse with how the scope affects in nested while loops (in C programming)
I'm just a beginner to C programming, and i got 2 different outputs for the following 2 code blocks.
Code 1**
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i=0;
    while (i<5)
    {
        int j=1;
        while (j<=2*i+1)
        {
            printf("*");
            j++;
        }
        i++;
        printf("\n");
    }
}

Code 2*
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i=0;
    int j=1;

    while (i<5)
    {
        while (j<=2*i+1)
        {
            printf("*");
            j++;
        }
        i++;
        printf("\n");
    }
}

Please can anybody explain the reason for that?
Thanks for spending time reading my question. Your help will be highly appriciated.
The first code block returns :
*
***
*****
*******
*********
The 2nd code block returns:
*
**
**
**
**

In the first program the variable j is initialized to 1 every iteration of the outer loop.
In the second program the variable j is initialized only once, at the start of the program.
For the two programs to be equivalent the second program should be changed to:
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i=0;
    int j=1;

    while (i<5)
    {
        j = 1;  // Change here, resetting the variable j
        while (j<=2*i+1)
        {
            printf("*");
            j++;
        }
        i++;
        printf("\n");
    }
}

